# Java - installation pacakge javax.media.jai in Windows Seven X32

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, windows-7

This is a pretty simple question. .
I just download package javax.media.jai and installed according to instructions
[Download](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/downloads/download-1_1_2_01.html) and [Installation](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/INSTALL-1_1_2_01.html)

The downloaded objects :

1. jai-1_1_2_01-lib-windows-i586.exe
2. jai-1_1_2_01-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe
3. jai-1_1_2_01-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe

I'm using IDE Netbeans 6.8 and Operating system Windows7 x32.

but there is still error and the error said : package javax.media.jai does not exist.

How to solving this problems ?

Thanks for any help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Download this [zip file](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jai/1.1.2_01-fcs/jai-1_1_2_01-windows-i586-jar.zip)  and extract the jar.

Now add the location of the jar to the Netbeans.

In netbeans goto Properties -> Sources -> Compile tab and add the JAR file.

Comment: In source just there "add folder", but in libraries there compile tab. and i was add the jar. but nothing change and there are still error.

Comment: goto compile tab and add the jar file.

Comment: hello i had also same problem i had copy the path of the zar fie in complie tab but still the error is same pleas help me to get rid of that